# Sublime, altering behavior of highlighting definions upon mouse-hover

Tags: sublimetext3

I have a project with several classes which partly share functions while at other times the functions are different in code, but use the same name.

When hovering over a function name, Sublime highlights every file and line where that definition is found.

In my opinion it would be better if it actually included which class the different highlights belong to.

Is it possible to edit this in some way ?

[image]

Assume `systems.js` contains 4 different classes (1 base, 3 children). I  would like to append or prepend the shown strings by the class definition (fetchable via *prototype*).

Answer (score 1):

The hover popup mentioned in your question is powered by Sublime's internal symbol index, which is created in combination with the syntax definition that's used to syntax highlight files that you're editing. The Sublime syntax system is fairly context free; it parses the structure of the code but it doesn't contain any real structural information about it.

So for example it can determine that `getShots` is a function or method because of the syntax that was used to define it, but it doesn't know what class it came from.

The code for the hover popup is available in `Default/symbol.py` (you can use [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to examine it) and associates symbols under the cursor with other places that it's seen symbols with that name in other files in the project; it literally only knows the information that you see in the popup; places where things by that name are defined and places where things of that name are referenced.

So in one sense, the answer to your question is No; core sublime can't do that because it doesn't have enough code intelligence to be able to figure that sort of thing out; this is exacerbated by dynamic languages like JavaScript where things can theoretically change at runtime as well.

The primary reason for that is because Sublime is extensible enough to support literally every programming language instead of just focusing on one or two (as e.g. `PhpStorm` does), so it doesn't have the core code to determine the information required.

All that said, since Sublime is indeed extremely extensible, it's possible that external code that **does** specialize on a language could be leveraged by a package in order to provide the appropriate information.

Two examples of that are [SublimeCodeIntel](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeCodeIntel) and [LSP](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP) for example. I don't use either of them myself, so I don't know for sure how good a fit they might be in your workflow.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend you shift to Visual Studio Code majorly because sublime is an editor whereas vs code is an IDE. Also, it has very great extension support for all languages. I would recommend you to use jshint which the most popular plugin for js code available for almost all popular editors and IDEs. But still if you want to go with Sublime I suggest you following plugins:
https://www.sitepoint.com/essential-sublime-text-javascript-plugins/